# Java Swing, having a JComponent and a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to add a JComponent to a  JPanel and then display it in a window. I'm pretty sure I've got it right, but only the button in the panel shows ups.

```
//Component class
JFrame window=new JFrame("This is a window");
RcComponent component=new RcComponent();
JButton button= new Button("This is a  button");
JPanel panel=new JPanel();

panel.add(component);
panel.add(button);
window.add(panel);

window.setVisible(true);
```

Only the button shows up in the created window. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" an answer so people know the problem has been solved. You have not accepted an answer on any of your previous questions either.

Answer (score 2):

By default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout and a FlowLayout respects the preferred size of all components added to it.

If RcComponent is a custom component then you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the Dimension of the component.

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(...);
}
```

If you don't override this method, then the preferred size is 0, so there is nothing to display:

Comment: Could I change the layout in lieu of overriding the method?

Comment: `in lieu of overriding the method?` - overriding the method is the proper solution. All Swing components should return a reasonable Dimension. Of course you can still use a different layout manger as each layout manager works differently. For example a GridLayout ignores the preferred size of each component and makes both components the same size. But this is still not a reason to ignore the getPreferredSize() method. You should design your component to be used with any layout manager because the requirement may change from application to application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have missed the layout manager.

https://www.google.com/#q=java%20layout

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window=new JFrame("This is a window");
    JButton button= new JButton("This is a  button");
    JLabel lbl= new JLabel("This is a  label");
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();

    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(lbl);
    window.add(panel);
    window.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    window.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between setting the default closing operation and this?

Comment: The default layout of a `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`.

Comment: You can do more stuff here. Such as checking for unsaved documents, etc.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. How the simplest things elude me.

Comment: @tomse, Yes, my bad, it works with the default layout, as well :)

Comment: So the issue was with the window size.